# How to disable android studio import R.string

Tags: kotlin

When I use `"Extrace string resource"` make string in code to `strings.xml`. AS auto `import packetId.R.string`, my code show `getString(string.xxx)`. then can't jump to `string.xml`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you mean extract instead of extrace? You might want to [edit] the question to include a tag for android studio if this is related to the use of intentions within that program.

Answer (score -1):

`import packageId.R` into your class.

Comment: thanks, but in kotlin class, also auto import packetId.R.string.  this problem does not exit  in the java class.